# Alt+Numpad key codes on modern Windows laptops without numpad

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, special-characters, laptop

I am using the Windows Alt+Numpad method a lot on my desktop PC to enter special characters like n-dash (Alt+0150), hard space (Alt+0160), typographic quotes, bullets, etc. This method needs a numpad and a numlock key to switch the numpad to number output.

For roughly a decade I could also use this Alt+Numpad method on several old 15 inch Win-XP laptops (without a numpad) by holding down Fn+Alt and typing on a "simulated" numpad on the following keys:

```
789  -->  789
UIO  -->  456
JKL  -->  123
M    -->  0
```

On latest generation laptops I cannot find this method any more (tested on Dell XPS15z & Samsung Series 9). I searched the web for hours but all I could find are tips that seem outdated (using Fn+ScrollLock instead of Fn+Alt, etc - many modern 15 inch laptops have neither NumLock nor ScrollLock).

The Microsoft standard response ([example](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-hardware/using-alt-codes-on-laptop-without-num-lock/0cafea87-6ab0-414d-bbb0-e888a324c368)) is to use the Character Map to pick, copy and paste special characters, but this is **way to inefficient** for frequent usage.

Is there any method to quickly enter special characters on modern Win laptops? Maybe some additional software? I cannot believe that there is no efficient way to do this on modern machines that cost +1500 EUR.

Comment: You best solution would be to use a keyboard mapping software that's can produce any key based other key combinations (e.g.: CTRL+ALT) or based on a key state (e.g.: SCROLL-LOCK). You may want to try *Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator*, but third party software that can change the keyboard layout based on the SCROLL-LOCK state would be preferred since a lot of softwares uses CTRL/SHIFT/ALT combinations for menu shortcuts.

Comment: Any suggestions for a good mapping software? 
BTW: ScrollLock state is not a good approach as many modern laptops without numpad also don't have a ScrollLock key.

Comment: Try *AutoHotkey* (http://www.autohotkey.com/). It's highly customizable using scripts. Note that the `Fn` key doesn't have nor generate a key code.

Comment: Did you you find a decent solution? 
I am searching for something faster, than Alt+Digits. Something similar to Mac OS: Alt+Shift+- or Alt+- for m-n-dashes.

Comment: Mezhaka, I guess the answer of Joey below sums up pretty all options that you have. I did not yet vote up his answer because I did not find the time to test all his options. From reading alone it looks like AutoHotKey would allow to create shortcuts as you know them from Mac OS.

Comment: OMG more and more laptops ship without numpad on fn key - that's a disaster

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have encountered a laptop without a numpad yet, but I take your word for it.

I see a few options right now:

1. Buy a standalone USB numpad. Careful, though, as some just send the regular number key scancodes and thus cannot be used as a numpad for this purpose.
2. Create your own keyboard layout with [MSKLC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665.aspx) and include the characters you need, maybe as <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>Something</kbd>.
3. Create an [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script to input characters on certain keystrokes or replace entered text by different characters while typing (sort of like Word's AutoCorrect).
4. If the software you're working in uses RichEdit (this includes Word and WordPad) you can also type the hexadecimal code point value and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> (or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, depending on the application) to convert it into the appropriate character. That's how I type things like → all the time (because I do so mostly in IM programs which use RichEdit).

Comment: Could you point us to more reading about point 4? I love it! I would like to know the limits of this feature.

Comment: I can strongly recommend your third bullet, AutoHotKey never disappoints at getting things done.